# Why JsonStore provides a commitchanges method

Tags: extjs3

The extjs Jsonstore class has a method commitchanges().
Now considering that the javascript code will send an AJAX request to a servlet and not to a db directly, what do we need a commitchanges() method?

Comment: Your extjs code cannot communicate directly to your database.

Comment: Ok thanks...but what is the use of this method commitchanges()?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user changes anything in the form panel's or UI components that data is changed in record, but at this time record will maintain a list of modified properties in the record and store maintains a list of modified records in the store

So whenever you send a request to save the data to server, after successful save you will get back a success response, on this response store need to make sure that the saved record will be removed from the list of records that are modified in the store and also remove list of modifications from the record instance to indicate that save operation was successful

So the operations of removing list of modified properties from record instance is performed by `record.commit` method and operations of removing saved record from list of modified records from store is performed by `store.commitChanges` method which in turn will call `record.commit` for every record which is saved correctly on server